# How to fix ReferenceError not defined when passing props from Laravel blade to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use a Vue.js component in Laravel but cannot get props passed from the blade to the js component. Console is reporting `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: clientId is not defined"`

I've tried renaming the prop in the blade/js, using :client-id, client, v-client, etc., and simplified as much as I can but still can't make it work.
Looks almost exactly like a bit of code I've used successfully elsewhere.

show.blade.php

```
<archive-button client-id="1"></archive-button>
```

archiveButton.js

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["clientId"],

  mounted() {
    console.log("id:" + clientId);
  }
};
</script>
```

I expect the clientId to appear in the console as `id:1` but instead, it reports

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: clientId is not defined"

found in

---> <ArchiveButton> at resources/js/components/archiveButton.vue
```

Probably a schoolboy error, but I've been staring at it and scratching my head for ages... Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Should be `this.clientId`.  Now I feel stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Laravel

Change

```
  mounted() {
    console.log("id:" + clientId);
  }
```

to

```
  mounted() {
    console.log("id:" + this.clientId);
  }
```

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks, thissven. Should be `this.clientId`. I sussed it seconds after posting this. Rubber Duck debugging at its finest. </feelingstupid>

Comment: Glad I could help